# Too Many Software in Autoremove

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, uninstall, unity8

I've done a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.10 recently and after it's finished, just installed my basics like Chrome, Calibre, Spotify, Steam, OpenVPN and things like that. Nothing that needs an unusual thing to do.

After it's all done and working fine, I've rebooted my computer. Then the next day, I've done my usual `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` check. When I said upgrade, autoremove said there are software can be uninstalled. But the list was huge and included many interesting things. List is something like that:

```
    account-plugin-tools accountsservice-ubuntu-schemas
  accountsservice-ubuntu-touch-schemas address-book-service apparmor-easyprof
  apparmor-easyprof-ubuntu biometryd-bin cgmanager click-apparmor
  evolution-data-server-utouch folks-common gir1.2-click-0.4 gir1.2-gee-0.8
  history-service indicator-network indicator-transfer
  indicator-transfer-download-manager libbiometryd1 libboost-locale1.61.0
  libboost-serialization1.61.0 libcapnp-0.5.3 libconnectivity-qt1 libdbus-cpp5
  libfolks-eds25 libfolks25 libhistoryservice0 libindicator-transfer0
  libjsoncpp1 libleveldb1v5 liblightdm-qt5-3-0 libmission-control-plugins0
  libnet-cpp2 libonline-accounts-daemon1 libonline-accounts-qt1 libpam-cgfs
  libpay2 libprocess-cpp3 libqdjango-db0 libqgsttools-p1 libqmenumodel0
  libqofono-qt5-0 libqt5contacts5 libqt5multimedia5-plugins
  libqt5multimediaquick-p5 libqt5multimediawidgets5 libqt5sensors5
  libqt5systeminfo5 libqt5versit5 libqt5xmlpatterns5 libsystemsettings1
  libtelepathy-qt4-2 libtelepathy-qt5-0 libthumbnailer-qt1.0 libtrust-store2
  libubuntu-application-api3 libubuntu-location-service3
  libubuntu-platform-hardware-api3 libubuntuoneauth-2.0-0 libudm-priv-common1
  libunity-api0 libunity-scopes1.0 libusermetricsinput1 libusermetricsoutput1
  libzmqpp4 mir-client-platform-mesa5 mir-graphics-drivers-desktop
  mir-platform-graphics-mesa-kms10 mir-platform-graphics-mesa-x10
  mir-platform-input-evdev5 pay-service pay-ui policykit-unity8
  python3-apparmor python3-apparmor-click python3-libapparmor qmenumodel-qml
  qml-module-biometryd qml-module-ofono qml-module-pamauthentication0.1
  qml-module-qmltermwidget1.0 qml-module-qtmultimedia
  qml-module-qtquick-xmllistmodel qml-module-qtsysteminfo
  qml-module-ubuntu-connectivity qml-module-ubuntu-onlineaccounts2
  qml-module-ubuntu-settings-components qml-module-ubuntu-thumbnailer0.1
  qml-module-ubuntuone qtcontact5-galera qtdeclarative5-gsettings1.0
  qtdeclarative5-qtmir-plugin qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-settings-components
  qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-telephony0.1 qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-web-plugin
  qtdeclarative5-unity-notifications-plugin qtmir-desktop qtubuntu-desktop
  signon-plugin-password sqlite3 telepathy-mission-control-5 telephony-service
  thumbnailer-service tone-generator ubuntu-app-launch ubuntu-app-launch-tools
  ubuntu-application-api3-desktop ubuntu-application-api3-test
  ubuntu-download-manager ubuntu-keyboard-data ubuntu-push-client
  ubuntu-snappy-cli ubuntu-terminal-app ubuntuone-client-data
  ubuntuone-credentials-common unity-plugin-scopes unity8-common
  unity8-private usermetricsservice xmir
```

It seems like it's trying to uninstall Unity 8 but I didn't asked it to do or anything to trigger that.

As far as I can understand, it doesn't seem like something that can cause any trouble but I wanted to get your comments about it and wanted to ask if it's fine to go with the autoremove command.